# How to convert Mongo ObjectID to String Id while querying documents MongoDB version 3.6.18

Tags: database, mongodb, grails, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document in MongoDB.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5f9a3056be496aec564bca"),
    "field1" : "value1",
    "field2" : "value2",
}
```

How can I query this and get the `ObjectId` as `String`. like below

```
{
    "_id" : "5d5f9a3056be496aec564bca",
    "field1" : "value1",
    "field2" : "value2",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$toString` operator to do this task.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        $toString: "$_id",

      },
      field1: 1,
      field2: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. DB version is 3.6.18

Answer (score 0):

On MongoDB version >= `4.0` - You'll have an option to convert the type of the field, Here you can use [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/index.html) to convert it to string :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** `$addFields` will overwrite the existing value of field if a field exists with same name,
   *   if not will create a new additional field on doc */
  {
    $addFields: {
      _id: {
        $toString: "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HhtCi94k4e6)

**Note :** On version below `4.0` there is no way to convert `ObjectId()` to string using MongoDB query unless you use any code to do it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. DB version is 3.6.18

Comment: @ShamnadPS : So as I said there is no way to convert `ObjectId()` to `String` in query for version prior to `4.0` but when you read results in code as `ObjectId()` is not a supported type of `JSON` it will by default be converted to string !! But converting in query is not possible..

Comment: Could you please share a reference of  how to do that please.

Comment: Right now I read it as a document and convert to my Object in which Id is of type String and I get data conversation error saying ObjectID cannot be type cast to String

Comment: @ShamnadPS : What are you trying to do ? Are you trying to read docs and convert `ObjectId()` to String in code ?

Comment: @ShamnadPS : Not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but if you're reading docs from collection & print result in code in general you won't see `ObjectId()` cause it's not JSON supported formatted it will by default be converted to string..

Comment: This works. Is there a better option? ```def tickets = Ticket.collection.find().map({it._id = it._id.toString(); return it }).collect({it as Ticket})```

Comment: @ShamnadPS : I still believe it will be a string by default, but as I said you can't do it in query, code has to do if anything needed - Yes that's the only option !